# Grouping based on and plotting error statistics in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have implemented a regression model and retrieved results. Now to evaluate the results I want to create plot, where MAE, and its standard deviation are represented in the same figure. However, I want to group the date into intervals and evaluate statistics. Though, I can use sklearn metrics for calculating mean absolute error, it works on entire range of data. Can some one give an idea about how to group the data based on intervals.

The data is very large hence, could not share here. However, random data and implemented code for calculating bias, I am attaching below.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
yact = random.sample(range(1, 100), 50)
ypred=random.sample(range(1, 100), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(yact,columns=['yact'])
df['ypred']=ypred
df['bias']=df['yact']-df['ypred']
#groups=[20,40,60,80,100]
```

I want to creat groups of y pred based on yact (similar to groups given above).
A reference figure which I am trying to plot is present in the first quadrant of below attached figure.

[image: Reference figure I am trying to plot is present in the 1st quadrant]

Comment: So, you would have five subplots for the five `yact` groups or five summarized groups within one plot? And if you have grouped your data based on their `yact` value - what do you plot then? What is the x-value, what the y-value, what kind of plot do you expect? A scatter plot with mean/sd error bars per group?

Comment: It will be a single plot. Y axis values will be with ypred values. x value will be groups divided based on yact. A scatter plot with mean and sd bars per group will be plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use only pandas/matplotlib but seaborn makes this kind of plotting so much easier. First, we categorize the data with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) based on the bins provided, then we plot them with [seaborns pointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot). The estimator `mean` is the default but I wanted to point out that you can feed other functions here into the plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#random data generation
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
n=500
yact = rng.choice(range(1, 100), n)
ypred = rng.choice(range(1, 100), n)
df = pd.DataFrame({"yact": yact, "ypred": ypred})
df['bias']=df['yact']-df['ypred']

#binning of data
bins = [0, 30, 50, 80, 100]
labels = [f"({first}; {second}]" for first, second in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]
df["cats"] = pd.cut(x=df['yact'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

#plotting with seaborn
sns.pointplot(x="cats", y="ypred", data=df, order=labels, estimator=np.mean, ci="sd", join=False)

plt.show()
```

(Unsurprisingly uniform) sample output:

[image]